# PHP, Javascript & Twig Temaples

Tags: javascript, php, symfony, twig

I have this code to show points on a google map which I just can't quite get to work when I pass the information from my PHP to my Twig template.  However it works just fine with an array directly in the javascript.  Please can somewhere spare my hair pulling and help me out.

**PHP code:**

```
// Create a list of items return from SQL
foreach ($mapdetails as $mapdetail){
if($locations!='') $locations.=','; 
$locations.='[
"'.$mapdetail['venue'].'"
,"'.$mapdetail['lat'].'"
,"'.$mapdetail['lng'].'"
]';    
}

// set template variables & render template
echo $template->render(array (
'pageTitle' => 'Map Locations',
'locations' => $locations
));
```

echoing $locations returns this:
[ "Venue 1","53.301624" ,"-1.923434" ],[ "Venue 2"  ,"53.160526" ,"-1.996968" ]

**JAVASCRIPT SNIPPET:**

**When I use this line in the template it doesn't work**

`var all = '[{{locations|json_encode()|raw}}]';`

**When I use this line it does work**

```
var all =  [[ "Venue 1" ,"53.301624" ,"-1.923434" ],[ "Venue 2","53.160526" ,"-1.996968"]];
```

**FULL JAVASCRIPT**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true"></script>

    <script>
        // Set the Map variable
        var map;

        function initialize(){ 
            var myOptions ={
              zoom: 9,
              mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            };
```

**THIS DOESN'T WORK When replaced with the below line it does**

```
var all = '[{{locations|json_encode()|raw}}]';
```

**THIS DOES WORK**

```
var all =  [[ "Venue 1" ,"53.301624" ,"-1.923434" ],[ "Venue 2","53.160526" ,"-1.996968"]];

console.log(all);

        var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), myOptions);

        // Set the center of the map
        var pos = new google.maps.LatLng(53.25,-1.91);
        map.setCenter(pos);

        function infoCallback(infowindow, marker) { 
            return function() {
            infowindow.open(map, marker);
        };
   }      
   function setMarkers(map, all) {  
    for (var i in all) {                    
            var venue  = all[i][0];
            var lat   = all[i][1];
            var lng   = all[i][2];
            var latlngset;

            latlngset = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);

            console.log(venue);
            console.log(lat);


            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({  
              map: map,  title: city,  position: latlngset  
            });
            var content = '';       

            var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

              infowindow.setContent(content);

              google.maps.event.addListener(
                marker, 
                'click', 
                infoCallback(infowindow, marker)
              );
          }
        }     
        // Set all markers in the all variable
        setMarkers(map, all);
      };
      // Initializes the Google Map
      google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map_canvas" style="height: 500px; width: 800px;"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Any help please....

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you're creating a PHP string:

```
'[ "Venue 1","53.301624" ,"-1.923434" ],[ "Venue 2" ,"53.160526" ,"-1.996968" ]'
```

which you are the json_encoding (with added quotes and stuff to boot):

```
var all = '[{{locations|json_encode()|raw}}]';
```

The result of which is something like this, which is a messed up Javascript string and not an object:

```
var all = '["[ \"Venue 1\",\"53.301624\"..."]';
```

That's nowhere close to what you want. You simply want to have a *PHP array* which you then json_encode:

```
$locations = array_map(function (array $mapdetail) {
    return array($mapdetail['venue'], $mapdetail['lat'], $mapdetail['lng']);
}, $mapdetails);
```

In the template:

```
var all = {{ locations|json_encode|raw }};
```

The result looks like:

```
var all = [["Venue 1","53.301624","-1.923434" ],["Venue 2","53.160526","-1.996968"]];
```

which is a Javascript array of arrays. It's that simple.

Comment: Thank you very much, only issue I'm getting now is it's only placing 1 location on the map. When dumping out $locations I get: Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => Venue 1 [1] => 53.301624 [2] => -1.923434 ) [1] => Array ( [0] => Venue 2 [1] => 53.160526 [2] => -1.996968 ) )  Which I think the javascript isn't handling each array element correctly, thoughts??

Comment: Sorry now sorted it.  Truly Thank you for this simple solution for an issue that was driving me bonkers.